# How do I use a PPTP/OpenVPN connection as a SOCKS/HTTP proxy?

Tags: linux, windows, proxy, openvpn, pptp

I would like to use a PPTP or OpenVPN as a socks proxy, that way instead of funneling all traffic from my PC through it I would instead use that connection to create a SOCKS or HTTP proxy that I could use with any supported program.

How would I do this on both Linux and Windows (not at the same time of course)?

Comment: I don't think this makes any sense at all.  VPN is not a  socks Proxy  and a socks proxy is not a VPN

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this.

1. You need to connect to the VPN without it taking over your whole network, but still have the VPN's interface useable.  I've done that with OpenVPN, by adding lines to the config file:

   ```cpp
   route-noexec         # Don't add or remove routes automatically

   script-security 2    # Allow user-defined scripts to be called
   down down.sh         # Run script called "down.sh" when connection goes down
   up up.sh             # Run script called "up.sh" when connection comes up
   ```

   - `up.sh` script

     ```bash
     #!/bin/sh

     VPN_IP=$ifconfig_local
     VPN_GATEWAY=$route_vpn_gateway

     # Route packets from the VPN's IP address to the VPN's gateway
       ip rule   add   from        $VPN_IP       table vpn
       ip route  add   default via $VPN_GATEWAY  table vpn

       ip route flush cache
     ```
   - `down.sh` script

     ```bash
     #!/bin/sh

     VPN_IP=$ifconfig_local
     VPN_GATEWAY=$route_vpn_gateway

     # Flush table and delete the rule
       ip route  flush table vpn
       ip rule   del   from  $VPN_IP table vpn

       ip route  flush cache
     ```
2. For the scripts to work, you need to create a new routing table, called `vpn`, by issuing: 
    `echo 1 vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

   - You have to do this only once.  The scripts implement policy routing.  Their purpose is to ensure any packets sent through the VPN tunnel are routed to the appropriate gateway address (i.e. the VPN's default route is correctly set up, but used only by programs that connect directly to the tunnel).
3. Bring up the VPN connection by issuing: `openvpn config-file.conf`

   - Your computer will now have an extra interface you can use directly, called `tun0`.  Some programs (qBittorrent for example) will allow you to specify the interface to connect to.  Choosing `tun0` ensures all of the program's network traffic uses the VPN.

To achieve the OP's requested goal, you can install the socks server called [Dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/).

- Part of the configuration for Dante is to set the internal and external interfaces.

  - For the internal, and depending on from where you wish to connect, use either the loopback interface (i.e. `lo`) or your main network interface (i.e.  `eth0`).
  - For the external, use `tun0`,  ensuring all network traffic over socks is routed through the VPN.

---

Example `openvpn.conf`

```bash
client
dev tun0
remote some-openvpn-server.somewhere.net 53     # Replace this by a real server url
proto udp
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
ca ca.crt
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
float
route-method exe
route-delay 2
route-noexec          # Stop the connection taking over the whole machine
up up.sh              # Run the script called "up" when the connection comes up
down down.sh          # Run the script called "down" when the connection goes down
script-security 2     # Allow scripts to be called
auth-user-pass me     # Use the login credentials from the file called "me"
auth-retry interact
explicit-exit-notify 2
ifconfig-nowarn
auth-nocache
```

Comment: The [OpenVPN man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) explains what each option does.

Comment: An off-topic FYI, as this occurs all too often, AES-256-CBC is wholly unnecessary since AES-128 will remain uncrackable for some time.  If you're really concerned, simply change the rekey values to a lower time and data limit _(every 5min /100MB data, etc.)_  All one does by using AES-256 is massively slow throughput to a crawl for zero security gain (`openssl speed aes-128-cbc aes-256-cbc`) .  You may also want to ask your VPN provider why they're not providing OpenVPN 2.4, which added support for EC ciphers _(they're more efficient)_, TLS-Crypt, and changed compression to LZ4.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! I was looking for this and spending many hours looking for solutions. But this is the only native solution that actually works! (most other solutions come with container solutions which I don't like)

Answer (score 2):

For OpenVPN, there's a [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/openvpn-devel/thread/1397366216-657-1-git-send-email-cernekee%40gmail.com/) for ocproxy support, but it's outdated (for 2.3.x branch). I've ported it to the [recent 2.5](https://github.com/ValdikSS/openvpn-tunpipe), but this is PoC (Windows not supported, yet).
You can use it with [ocproxy](https://github.com/cernekee/ocproxy) or [tunsocks](https://github.com/russdill/tunsocks), which expose VPN as a SOCKS/HTTP proxy.

FYI, there's similar projects for WireGuard: [wghttp](https://github.com/zhsj/wghttp/), [wg-http-proxy](https://github.com/shimberger/wg-http-proxy), [wireproxy](https://github.com/octeep/wireproxy), [onetun](https://github.com/aramperes/onetun)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this [OpenVPN, L2TP, or PPTP client that is a SOCKS5 server | linux](https://superuser.com/questions/787063/openvpn-l2tp-or-pptp-client-that-is-a-socks5-server-linux)
May be some container or virtual machine to act as a bridge - it'll have pptp interface and a socks proxy server inside. You'll need somehow to address socks traffic to the port configured for the service by any other tool you like (some port forwarding)

Comment: You linked a question without an answer. Did you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749741/1333493 or what?

Comment: I do realize, that I linked a question without answer. The purpose was to show the direction to dig further, because initial question didn't make sense.
As you have noticed I further described what need to be done to solve the task.
Anyway, I've never done anything like that and unfortunately I have no instructions how to do it, but with the directions I gave, those can be acquired from any linux admin with some networking skills.
So rephrasing the question and creating a new topic would be a good suggestion imho.