# Can I access multiple OpenVPN connections, each accessed through socks proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn, socks-proxy

I have a piece of software, I'll call it "FooSoft" here, which needs to connect to multiple devices on networks protected by a variety of third party VPNs. Each VPN is independent and I have no control over the setup of these VPNs or the network behind them. FooSoft supports connecting to socks5 proxies to transfer data.

If I use [OpenConnect with ocproxy](https://github.com/cernekee/ocproxy) it seems that I can have a socks5 proxy that FooSoft connects to, and that only this traffic is directed through the particular VPN connection, allowing me to have multiple VPN connections, each behind a socks5 proxy and not interfering with one another (right?).

However, it's not clear that the same is possible for OpenVPN? The [documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/) mentions an option `socks-proxy`, but I'm not sure if this expects there to be an existing socks proxy running already or if it creates one and routes the traffic through it.

The current architecture is this:

```
customer 1 <---> FooSoft direct IP access
OpenVPN          to devices on customer 
                 network
```

The kind of architecture I am imagining is something like this:

```
FooSoft <---> socks proxy 1 <-> customer 1  <-> direct IP access
          :                     OpenVPN         to devices on  
          :                                     customer network
          :
          :
          :-> socks proxy 2 <-> customer 2  <-> direct IP access
          :                     OpenVPN         to devices on  
          :                                     customer network
          :
          :
          :-> socks proxy 3 <-> customer 3  <-> direct IP access
                                OpenVPN         to devices on  
                                                customer network
```

Therefore, my question is, how can connect to one or more simultaneous OpenVPN VPN connections each through a corresponding socks proxy?

**EDIT**

Since posting the question I found the following docker projects. I am interested to understand if this approach will achieve what I want.

[openvpn-socks5](https://github.com/saronqw/openvpn-socks5)

[docker-openvpn-socks5](https://github.com/curve25519xsalsa20poly1305/docker-openvpn-socks5)

[docker-openvpn-client-socks](https://github.com/kizzx2/docker-openvpn-client-socks)

Comment: IIRC, and I may be wrong, you can connect to multiple OpenVPN profiles at the same time by creating extra vLAN tun/tap adapters, but I'm unsure how integrating a socks5 proxy would be done

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/a/1822649/23156) help you?

Comment: @FrankThomas FooSoft is running on an AWS instance running Windows Server 2022. In the current scenario I am running a standard VPN client on this machine, and configures Foosoft to not use any proxy. It connects directly to IP addresses on the site network (i.e. inside the VPN). FooSoft is unaware of the VPN. However, FooSoft has an option to route traffic for each 'site' through a socks proxy. For each proxy you specify the portI would be happy to have a separate linux server acting as a gateway to multiple sites and running multiple VPN clients on it and socks proxies.

Comment: @Michaelcomelately, it might help, I had a look, but the documentation seems to be sparse.

Comment: @FrankThomas, sorry, to add to my previous comment for each proxy you can specify the IP or hostname, port, and username and password. The software isn't very well documented in this area unfortunately.

Comment: @FrankThomas, possibly nothing. The issue I am concerned about is that I have no control over the networks behind each VPN. What if the IP addresses overlap? There might be devices I need to connect to behind each VPN that have the same IP address.

Comment: @FrankThomas, ok, but the documentation at the link I provided for ocproxy specifies this exact use case as being an issue it can solve. I have also since posting found a couple of docker projects, [openvpn-socks5](https://github.com/saronqw/openvpn-socks5) and [docker-openvpn-socks5](https://github.com/curve25519xsalsa20poly1305/docker-openvpn-socks5), that also look like they might do what I want.

Comment: Docker containers can be treated like individual servers for the purpose of networking, so that would be equivalent to running each pair of proxy+vpn on a dedicated host. I'll clean up my comments on your thread, and perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: @crobar If you get something working, please take the time to self-answer. I'd be interested to see what you did, particularly if a single container was able to route multiple VPN connections.